# How can I save user data to Firestore in Flutter using the Firebase Database?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

```dart
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:aveloux/components/validator.dart';

class SignUpView extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignUpView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SignUpView> createState() => _SignUpViewState();
}

class _SignUpViewState extends State<SignUpView> {
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>(); // Create a GlobalKey for the form
  bool obscureText = true; // Boolean to toggle password visibility
  final usernameController = TextEditingController(); // Controller for the username input field
  final passwordController = TextEditingController(); // Controller for the password input field
  final emailController = TextEditingController(); // Controller for the email input field

  // Function to toggle password visibility
  void togglePasswordVisibility() {
    setState(() {
      obscureText = !obscureText;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                # unsolicited code...
                Form(
                  key: formKey, // Associate the form with the GlobalKey
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'Username',
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleMedium,
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 12),
                      TextFormField(
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                        textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter your username'),
                        controller: usernameController, // Connect the controller to the username field
                        validator: Validator.usernameValidator, // Use a validator function to validate input
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 12),
                      Text(
                        'Email',
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleMedium,
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 12),
                      TextFormField(
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                        textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter your email'),
                        controller: emailController, // Connect the controller to the email field
                        validator: Validator.emailValidator, // Use a validator function to validate input
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 12),
                      Text(
                        'Password',
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleMedium,
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 12),
                      TextFormField(
                        controller: passwordController, // Connect the controller to the password field
                        obscureText: obscureText, // Hide or show the password
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: 'Enter your password',
                          suffixIcon: IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(obscureText ? Icons.visibility_off : Icons.visibility),
                            onPressed: togglePasswordVisibility, // Toggle password visibility
                          ),
                        ),
                        validator: Validator.passwordValidator, // Use a validator function to validate input
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 24),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    if (formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                      final username = usernameController.text;
                      final email = emailController.text;
                      final password = passwordController.text;

                      try {
                        UserCredential userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance
                            .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password); 
                        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(userCredential.user?.uid).set({
                          'email': email,
                          'username': username,
                          'password': password,
                        });
                      } catch (error) {
                        print('Error registering user: $error');
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  style: ButtonStyle(
                    minimumSize: MaterialStateProperty.all(const Size(double.infinity, 48)),
                  ),
                  child: const Text('Sign Up'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have successfully initialized Firebase Authentication in my `main.dart` for user registration. Now, I want to take the user's data and store it in a Firestore collection. How can I achieve this?

I'm looking for guidance on how to:

1. Store the user's data in the "users" collection, including the username, password, and email.
2. Ensure that the data is securely and correctly saved to Firestore, and be available for later usage.

Comment: It doesn't look like you haven't made any attempt to write the code yourself.  Generally, on Stack Overflow, it's expected that you make an attempt, then post a question that shows what you tried, and what specifically isn't working the way you expect, along with your debugging information.

Comment: @DougStevenson My mistake, that was my outdated code, when interacting with the "ElevatedButton" structure, the action of gathering text from text controllers and saving it to the "users" collection within my Firestore database has been accompanied by a recurring error: "Error registering user: [firebase_auth/configuration-not-found] Error."

Comment: make sure you set-up your firebase you can use (firebase cli) or  directly register your platform within firebase and also make sure your firestore roles allows you to read and write.